# First time using c#, It says I have error CS1513

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this to make a game in unity, and in unity it also says error `CS1513:} expected`

```
public class GunFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            AudioSource gunfire = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            gunfire.Play();
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("gunRecoil");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: you need another } at the end

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've lost a closing `}` for your class body.

```
public class GunFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            AudioSource gunfire = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            gunfire.Play();
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("gunRecoil");
        } 
    }
}    // this one
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you forgot to close the code for your class.

You must close your class with another brace:

```
public class GunFire : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            AudioSource gunfire = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            gunfire.Play();
            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("gunRecoil");
        } 
    }
} // Here
```

Answer (score 1):

[Compiler Error CS1513](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513) means that there are not enough closing braces compared to opening braces.

To solve the error, simply add a closing brace `}` to the bottom of the file. You should have three of them.